# Installing Petsc on Windows

Tags: python, cygwin, mpi, scientific-computing, petsc

I installed cygwin with python, make and diffutils.

When I am using the command:

```
./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-mpich --download-fblaslapack
```

I am getting an error "**Windows Python Detected. Please rerun ./configure with cygwin-python**".

If I use the command at the cygwin commandline

```
python setup.py install
```

I am getting the following runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 314, in <module>
    **metadata)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 230, in run
    config(prefix, self.dry_run)
  File "setup.py", line 166, in config
    if status != 0: raise RuntimeError(status)
RuntimeError: 3
```

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building on Cygwin do NOT mix with Windows version of Python
so sanitize your PATH to have only cygwin program in it:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/lapack"
./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran
```

about this two settings

```
--download-mpich --download-fblaslapack
```

cygwin has its own OpenMPI, Blas and Lapack packages,
so you should use them.
The package names are:

```
$ cygcheck -cd |grep openmpi
libopenmpi-devel                        3.1.6-1
libopenmpi40                            3.1.6-1
libopenmpifh40                          3.1.6-1
libopenmpiusef08_40                     3.1.6-1
libopenmpiusetkr40                      3.1.6-1
openmpi                                 3.1.6-1

$ cygcheck -cd |grep "lapack\|openblas"
liblapack-devel                         3.9.0-2
liblapack0                              3.9.0-2
libopenblas                             0.3.9-1
```

I am not sure but MPICH, but it will very likely NOT build under Cygwin

Comment: I am getting error "python not found in /usr/bin/env : No such file or directory"

Comment: install python package in cygwin

Comment: I have installed python during cygwin installation.

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -f /usr/bin/python` ?